Masonry layout with the same equal columns and spacing
I have a problem with developing following columns layout:
enter image description here
Please note: i dont exatcly know how many rows and columns i will have, but as per image it will be 3 columns per row and probably on the smaller device will go to two per row and finnaly 1 per row.
What would be the best way of achiving something like that?
Currently i have in use flexbox:
<div class="row gy-45 gy-md-0 gx-md-90">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 grid-column"></div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 grid-column"></div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 grid-column"></div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 grid-column"></div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 grid-column"></div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 grid-column"></div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 grid-column"></div>
</div>

and to get this layout similar to the image i have added this css rule:
.grid-column:nth-child(3n + 1),
      .grid-column:nth-child(3n + 3) {
        margin-top: 15%;
        margin-bottom: -10%;
}

This however distrub the flow of the document and element like button is overlapping row:
enter image description here
